# Finding sup and inf

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

We will let $f: (a,b) \to R$ be a differentiable map,  and define two sets,  $A = \left\{f'(x) : x \in (a,b) \right\}$ and $B = \left\{\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} : x  \neq y \in (a,b) \right\}$.

I know that $\sup B$ and $\inf A$ are different. I would like to find $\sup B$ and $\inf A$. I am also trying to think about and counterexample to analyse here. Another option would try by contradiction that $\sup B$ and $\inf A$ are different.

I just need something to work on to get started. Any ideas?

Comment: Mean value theorem

Comment: @martycohen how do I get started to use the theorem?

Comment: The first step to using the theorem is to go look it up. Contemplate on what it says. How does it relate the elements of $B$ to the elements of $A$?